# JMeter - Capture Data from Two CSV Files

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have 2 csv files

File 1:

```
         Name                 Start_Time
eml-alertservice               19:42:12
eml-redis                      19:42:12
eml-fluentd                    19:42:12
eml-kube-prometheus-stack      19:42:13
mwl-query-service              19:42:13
eml-grafana                    19:42:13
entity-management-service      19:42:14
snomed-service                 19:44:04
nuevo-dcm-services-wado        19:44:05
eis-common-postgres            19:45:43
```

File 2:

```
   OS         K3s        Duration
18:10:06    18:10:45     39 secs
18:53:38    18:54:17     39 secs
20:03:19    20:03:58     39 secs
16:27:45    16:28:51     66 secs
19:38:12    19:39:12     60 secs
```

Whole Data from File 1 is to be captured. From File 2, only the 2nd column from last row is to be extracted (Number of rows are dynamic). These are to be written into another file. The output could look something like

File 3:

```
         Name                 Start_Time      K3s
eml-alertservice               19:42:12     19:39:12
eml-redis                      19:42:12     19:39:12
eml-fluentd                    19:42:12     19:39:12
eml-kube-prometheus-stack      19:42:13     19:39:12
mwl-query-service              19:42:13     19:39:12
eml-grafana                    19:42:13     19:39:12
entity-management-service      19:42:14     19:39:12
snomed-service                 19:44:04     19:39:12
nuevo-dcm-services-wado        19:44:05     19:39:12
eis-common-postgres            19:45:43     19:39:12
```

Thanks for your support.

Regards,
Ajith

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in JMeter most probably the best option is going for [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) language somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test).

Example code:

```
def file1 = new File('file1.csv').readLines()
def file2 = new File('file2.csv').readLines()

file1.each { line ->
    new File('file3.csv') << line << ',' << file2.get(file2.size() - 1).split(',')[2] << System.getProperty('line.separator')
}
```